# GenericSignatureFormatError Signature Parse error

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a problem with my code. Code works on other computers but not on my.
I read about solving this problem but solution with change jdk to  http://jdk8.java.net/lambda/ and still don't work. Any idea?

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError: Signature Parse error: expected ')'
sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.error(SignatureParser.java:124) ~[na:1.8.0-ea]
        at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseFormalParameters(SignatureParser.java:586) ~[na:1.8.0-ea]
        at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseMethodTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:576) ~[na:1.8.0-ea]
        at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseMethodSig(SignatureParser.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0-ea]
        at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.parse(ConstructorRepository.java:55) ~[na:1.8.0-ea]
        at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.parse(ConstructorRepository.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0-ea]
        at sun.reflect.generics.repository.AbstractRepository.<init>(AbstractRepository.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0-ea]
        at sun.reflect.generics.repository.GenericDeclRepository.<init>(GenericDeclRepository.java:48) ~[na:1.8.0-ea]
        at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.<init>(ConstructorRepository.java:51) ~[na:1.8.0-ea]
        at sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.<init>(MethodRepository.java:46) ~[na:1.8.0-ea]
        at sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.make(MethodRepository.java:59) ~[na:1.8.0-ea]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericInfo(Method.java:101) ~[na:1.8.0-ea]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericReturnType(Method.java:249) ~[na:1.8.0-ea]
        at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXClass.getDeclaredMethodProperties(JavaXClass.java:113) ~[hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar:4.0.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXClass.getDeclaredProperties(JavaXClass.java:129) ~[hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar:4.0.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXClass.getDeclaredProperties(JavaXClass.java:121) ~[hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar:4.0.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:775) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3845) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3799) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1412) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        ... 60 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Look like some bug see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27383831/strange-error-in-hibernate-javafx-java-lang-reflect-genericsignatureformaterro

Comment: I see it before but still don't have solution

Comment: Not sure brother check their bug list

Comment: I also faced the similar error... It would be more helpful if you can paste your whole stack-trace.

Comment: For me problem was solved when I updated from java 8.0_181 to 8.0_201

Answer (score 5):

I suspect, you might have use **default method** in **interface** and in that you may have used **lambda** expression.

I also faced similar error. In my case in *eclipse* environment, it was working fine. But when application was deployed to server, it was throwing signature parse error. I dig into it for almost a week , and then started reverting the changes and found out that root cause was **lambda** code used in **default** method of interface.

Answer (score 0):

In rare cases the signature from reflection does not match the proper signature inside JVM (reflection method add additional ";" to method signature). One of the solutions is to take the String representing the signature, changing it manually and then passing it further (it's not the best way, but sometimes there's no other option).